# How to add field of another table in Add Custom Filter Drop down in tree view of other table in odoo 9?

Tags: odoo-9

I'm working on odoo 9. I have a model which has many2one field. I want to add this Many2one's specific property to Add Custom Filter drop down. Is this possible? Kindly guide me how can I do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *domain* both in Python as well as in XML

Python:

```
bank_account_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner.bank', string='Bank Account Number',
        domain="[('partner_id', '=', address_home_id)]", help='Employee bank salary account')
```

or in XML

```
<field name="bank_account_id" domain="[('partner_id', '=', address_home_id)]"/>
```

Comment: I dont think it should be remedy